# How to get Gmail to forward all mail from one specific domain

Tags: gmail

how i can get gmail to forward the all email from one specific domain i.e the mail which is received from domain1 to be forwarded to another email id but not from domain2, domain3 or any other to be forwarded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the steps in the following file, i hope this is what exactly you wanted :

[image]

[image]